# How to find id in Android App Using UIAutomator Viewer

Tags: java, android, selenium, android-uiautomator

I am writing automation test for Android/ios Mobile Apps. If someone has references to it.Let me know the sample code.

I have an Android app in which the Text elements is drawn

It extends View

And its drawn in onDraw method using Canvas

Where will the text present in the UIAutomator snapshot

Snapshot:-

[image: snapshot]

it is not in resource-id nor in text

How can I get this element for test automation

Snapshot represent the article title doesn't appear for all articles
[image]

Code Part:-

```
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Canvas;

import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.view.View;

public class MyView extends View {
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
Paint paint = new TextPaint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
canvas.drawText("Text to be written", x, y, paint);
}
}
```

Comment: Usually `resource-id` contains the id. But its not displaying in your case, probably you haven't applied one.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, app developers get accessibility support for free, courtesy of the View and ViewGroup classes. However, some apps use custom view elements to provide a richer user experience. Such custom elements won't get the accessibility support that is provided by the standard Android UI elements. If this applies to your app, make sure that it exposes the custom-drawn UI element to Android accessibility services by implementing the [AccessibilityNodeProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeProvider.html) class.

Read more at http://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing.html.